# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Error

Tags: java, file, parsing, file-io

I want to parse a numeric file. I achieve parsing but when I changed the file content, I get a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Any help will be appreciated.

My code is like below:

```
public void fileParse() throws IOException
{



    File f = new File("180214.txt");
    File f1 = new File("salelog.txt");

    String s = null;

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));


    while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
    {

            if(s.charAt(0) == '0')
            {
                pw.println("<receipt>");
                pw.println(s);
                continue;
            }
            if(s.charAt(0)=='8')
            {
                pw.println(s);
                pw.println("</receipt>");
                continue;
            }
            pw.println(s);

    }

//  br.close();
    pw.close();
    br1.close();

}

}
```

My file content is like this:

```
001021402180000000000000000                
4869359340051000000011001000000100000000000
58693593400510800000000008000    0         
600000001100100                            
800300000001070002075700000001100000000008 
001021402180000000000000000                
4869697119156000000003001000000100000000000
58696971191560800000000002000    0         
600000000300100                            
800500000001060002080000000000300000000002 
001021402180000000000000000                
4869069850477000000010001500000200000000000
58690698504770800000000015000    0         
4000008691497000000012001500000100000000000
50000086914970800000000009000    0         
4000004082260000000008001000000100000000000
50000040822600800000000006000    0         
600000004000100                            
800500000001060003080100000004000000000030 
001021402180000000000000000                
4000008090548000000028501400000100000000000
50000080905480800000000021000    0         
600000002850100                            
800500000001060004080900000002850000000021 
001021402180000000000000000                
4869088520157000000049501200000100000000000
58690885201571800000000076000    0         
600000004950100                            
800500000001060005080900000004950000000076 
001021402180000000000000000                
4869749799821000000019501400000100000000000
58697497998210800000000014000    0         
4869076767108000000049501500000100000000650
58690767671080800000000032000    0         
986907676710801$0000000065000001           
600000006250100                            
800500000001060006081200000006250000000046 
001021402180000000000000000                
4977214623561000000007503200000100000000000
59772146235610000000000000000    0         
600000000750100                            
800500000001060007081300000000750000000000
```

Comment: You have two BufferedReader elements. Are you using the right one?

Comment: what is the path to File "f1", it should be the first line in your file. Also post a stacktrace? What did you change in the file? Maybe you have an empty line somewhere in the file?

Comment: @user3465623 There is only one.

Comment: @user2382867 Try to use the "print" command instead of the "println" command.

Comment: you most probably have an empty line at the end of your text file. the content shown above works with the given code.

Comment: @user3465623 why would that matter?

Comment: @user3465623 print or println has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @user3465623  I edit the question. The other BufferedReader elemnt is not important.

Comment: @Moh-Aw Unfortunately there is no empty line at the end of my file. I can not put the entire file onto here because it is too big.

Comment: how about you build a try catch block around your code and catch the exception. in the catch block just print out s and you have the line that's causing the exception. (and/or count the lines incase the output is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing here, which can throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is the

```
s.charAt(0)
```

code.

That means that in this line on the first position there is nothing = empty line.

Try the following in the beginning of your loop:

```
if(s == null || s.trim().length() == 0)
{
    System.out.println("Empty line found.");
    continue;
}
```